# Rake aborted TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Buen día.
Estoy intentando instalar Redmine de forma manual y es mi primera vez.

Cuando ejecuto el comando `bundle exec rake db:migrate` me aparece el siguiente error:

> rake aborted!
> TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install
> C:/Ruby/redmine-5.0.0/config/environment.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'

> Caused by:
> TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound: None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories.
> C:/Ruby/redmine-5.0.0/config/environment.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)

Ya añadí la gema tzinfo-data pero aún así me eaprece el mismo error, qué debo de hacer?